# Python: How do I calculate the sum of numbers from a file?

Tags: python, arrays, file, calculation

How do I calculate the sum of numbers from a .txt file?

Data in file is formatted as:

```
7
8
14
18
16
8
23
...
```

I read the data from the file and assign every line value to 'line' vatiable, but I want to get something like: `result = 7+8+14+...`

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r')   #LOOP AND READ DATA FROM THE FILE
    for line in f:
        code
```

Comment: I want to calculate the sum of all the numbers, the 'n' just says the list goes on, 7+8+14+-19-23 ...Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = sum(map(int, f))
```

`int` is mapped over each line from `f`, then `sum()` adds up the resulting integers.

Comment: Thank you @Steven Rumbilski. But I get this error and think it's because the file has multiple lines to loop through:     with open('data.txt', 'r') as fin:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @MurphyAdam:  I forgot a closing parenthesis on my second line. Was that the issue?  It won't be because of multiple lines.  `sum()` drives the iteration over all the lines (indirectly by iteration over the results of `map()`).

Comment: Rumbilski Yes, of course! Haven't paid attention to it. Yeah, this is much simpler and works like a charm ^^ Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

This is most compact code I can think of right now:
(updated to handle the `n` at the end, thanks, @JonClements!)

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fin:
    ans = sum(int(line) for line in fin if line.strip().isnumeric())
```

For the code structure you have, you can also go for this:

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
ans = 0
for line in f:
    try:
        ans += int(line.strip())
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

**Edit:**
Since the confusion with the 'n' has been cleared, the first example can be as simple as

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fin:
    ans = sum(int(line) for line in fin)
```

Or even this one-liner:

```
ans = sum(int(line) for line in open('file.txt', 'r'))
```

But there are certain risks with file handling, so not strongly recommended.

Comment: What happens with the `'n'` at the end of the file? (and `for line in fin` is sufficient because `fin` supports an iterable interface.

Comment: Didn't notice that! @MurphyAdam Could you please explain?

Comment: @0605002 `.readlines()` will load all lines into memory - you don't need that for this as you can just sum over each line as you go... the other part is that `int('n')` will raise an exception...

Comment: You also don't need to .strip as int doesn't take leading/trailing whitespace into account anyway... you might be able to get away with just sum(int(line) for line in fin if line.strip().isdigit()) ( or .isnumeric() depending)

Comment: @AChampion that's what I said - it does appear that isdigit and isnumeric do though... so it's needed in one place...

Comment: @0605002 sorry - my bad - you will need to strip in the `if` check else nothing will happen because of the `\n`...

Comment: @0605002 regarding your second example... I'd also make it `except ValueError` to catch only the least amount the `pass` statement should deal with... if a keyboard interrupt or an `IOError` occurs... you should let that propagate to something that can handle it instead of swallowing it.

Comment: Just to note the OP clarified the `n` was just meant to indicate continuation, it looks like it just a list of numbers, so you can simplify back down to `sum(int(line) for line in f)`

Answer (score 2):

```
file = open("data.txt", "r")
numbers = []

for line in file:
  numbers.append(int(line))

print(sum(numbers))
```

This basically just creates a list of numbers, where each line is a new entry in the list. Then it shows the sum of the list.

Comment: You mean `int(line)` this isn't `C`.

Comment: Yes! Sorry, my main languages are C and C#.

Comment: That is correct. OP didn't specify how to handle that part. Using `if line.IsNumeric():` could be a potential solution here.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is, it will take care of the **\n** at the end of each line as well, based on steven's and AChamp's suggestion

```
with open("abc.txt","r")as f:
    print(sum(int(x) for x in f))
```

Comment: @StevenRumbalski absolutely correct updating my answer

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I needed @Inder much appreciation.

Comment: `for x in f` is sufficient. File-like objects support the iterable interface. This could me written `print(sum(map(int, f)))`

Comment: @MurphyAdam happy that I can help :)

Comment: @AChampion thank you for the suggestion made the edit, with due credits :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution (consider all of the lines are numbers):

```
def calculate_number_in_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        return sum([int(number.strip()) for number in f.readlines()])
```

Answer (score 1):

On smartphone...

```
with open(filepath) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
numbers = [int(line) for line in lines]
print(sum(numbers))
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure about that. And I had to fight a lot with autocorrect^^

Answer (score 1):

```
with open ('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

sum = 0
for line in data:
    sum += int(line.strip())

print(sum)
```

Comment: No need to read into `data`.  Just do it all under your with-statement: `for line in f: ...`.  Also no need to `.strip()` as `int()` can handle leading and trailing whitespace.